# Restkit keyPath issue, instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit

json response (from instagram)

```
{
  "meta": {
     "code": 200
  },
 "data": [
 {
  "username": "victoriassecret",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-19/11373751_810224469095258_1164651624_a.jpg",
  "id": "3416684",
  "full_name": "Victoria's Secret"
},
{
  "username": "vsco",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xtp1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11899636_1028996767152033_435823497_a.jpg",
  "id": "40238620",
  "full_name": "VSCO"
},
{
  "username": "vegas_nay",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpt1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12106144_1657363291168907_1032227973_a.jpg",
  "id": "19619019",
  "full_name": ""
  }
]
}
```

I am trying to get the `data` array out and map it into my object called `SocialFriend` :

```
 request.responseDescriptors = @[[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[WSISocialFriend mappingWithManagedObjectStore:wsi_managedObjectStore network:network]
                                                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                                                keyPath:@"data"
                                                                            statusCodes:WSIAPISuccessfulStatusCodes()]];
```

but after the objectRequestOperation finishes, if fails and this gets printed on my console

`NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: 
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: data, meta
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., keyPath=null, DetailedErrors=(
)}}, keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.}`

Why does it print that `keyPath=null`? I am missing something crucial here, any insight appreciated, thanks. I am content that my SocialFriend file is mapped just fine, but I need to get past the keyPath issue

Comment: Are you sure the code to add the descriptor is run?

Comment: @Wain it wasn't, works now, thanks for the hint! I had assumed my entire 'object' (which contained my requestDescriptor) was being read and run.